# RelationList wrong field value in tile schema

Tags: plone, relation

I have a tile with a relation field defined like this:

```
from z3c.relationfield.schema import RelationChoice
from z3c.relationfield.schema import RelationList

related_resources = RelationList(
    title=_(u"Linked resources"),
    required=False,
    value_type=RelationChoice(
        title=u"Multiple",
        source=ObjPathSourceBinder(portal_type=('Folder', 'Collection'))
    )
)
```

The problem is that when I add the tile, everything seems to work, and I get a value like

```
'related_resources': [<Folder at /Plone/images>]
```

even if I would expect to have a RelationValue in there.

When I restart plone, the same tile spit out this value for the field:

```
'related_resources': [<Folder at images>]
```

an object w/ a broken acquisition chain, thus a broken path.

The object is the same (I can get its brain via catalog and UID) but it's kind of broken.

Editing the tile also never work after a restart: the value disappear from the form and if I change some fields and save `related_resources` is lost.

Do I need a custom z3c.form datamanager for such a field? If so, I should it be implemented?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should not see

```
'related_resources': [<Folder at /Plone/images>]
```

but

```
'related_resources': [<RelationValue...>]
```

[RelationListDictDataManage](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.relationfield/commit/cd18d5cb2a4dceb37135a441ad6e820ae954cf81) was originally implemented into plone.app.relationfield just to support tiles. It did work, but it seems that at least we later ditched them in favor of using UUIDs for relations...

Yet, apparently something has got broken and the default attribute field data manager is used instead. You could add debugger into `z3c.form.form.applyChanges` to figure out, why it doesn't pick the correct datamanager.